# Kendo DateTimePicker Customization Issues

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-datetimepicker

I am facing one challenges, my requirement is to make datetimepicker as same as http://dojo.telerik.com/OrIrINir UI. I am using angular 9. I am unable to make datetimepicker UI as same as given in the link using angular 9. I gone through the documentation of Kendo UI with Angular but I found the different UI for datetimepicker.  Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was trying to modify the code but no luck. I was trying using this link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssbdxs?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Please check https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datetimepicker/

Comment: I mean, I was trying to make the UI same as http://dojo.telerik.com/OrIrINir link. There should be two icon ( for time and for date) in the same field. And when I click on timer icon it should open in dropdown format as shown in the given link.